# Are Ubuntu and Windows able to share disk space?

Tags: windows

I am using 2 hard disks within my notebook, a SSD with 250GB (Windows 10 is installled) and a HDD with 1TB.
If I want to install Ubuntu on my HDD use Windows when needed, would Windows be able to store some data and programs on that disk without creating a new partition like there would be no OS installled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible.

- Ubuntu can read / write files stored on a Windows NTFS partition out of the box, nothing further required.
- However, if you want to read / write files stored on an Ubuntu Ext4 partition from Windows, you'll need to install a driver or utility to do so - there's various options described in [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows).

So you have two options: Create a shared partition, and format it to NTFS, or install an Ext4 utitliy / driver in WIndows.

Comment: Creating a shared partition worked best for me. Thanks a lot.